How to make an ideal rectifier which can efficiently rectify 3 phase AC for power applications?
I'm working on a wind turbine project which needs to be able to rectify 3 phase AC with varying voltages. The lowest the input voltage will likely be is 2V, while the higher end will be 27V.
I've been using a 6 diode bridge rectifier for the mean time, but there is a lot of heat loss when the voltage is toward the lower end and a load is applied.
I've been searching for and reviewing some precision rectifiers online, since they are much more thermally efficient, but they all seem to be for audio and other low-power applications. My application will need to be able to accept up to 15 or so amps (when the voltage is low).
Are there any off-the-shelf precision rectifiers out there that can fulfill my project requirements?
If not, could somebody point me in the right direction on how to build one for a power application?
Again, this is really just an attempt to avoid heat losses.
Thank you!

Read some application notes on some parts and see if they fit within your design.

Questions: Q1. Do you have a datasheet for the wind turbine?  Q2.  What is the frequency range of the output voltage from the wind turbine?  Q3. What is the maximum power output of the wind turbine?

A rectifier from ideal diodes should minimise rectifier losses. But using little more than 120° conduction angle per phase may cause greater resistive loss in the generator. For another angle see How does conduction angle through a bridge rectifier affect generator performance?


I've been searching for and reviewing some precision rectifiers online

Precision rectifiers are signal processors, not power devices. What you're looking for is an ideal rectifier. Ideal rectifiers are usually implemented as a MOSFET whose body diode is the non-ideal rectifier, and whose channel acts as a shunt that turns the non-ideal body diode into an ideal rectifier.
Ideal rectifiers can be fully integrated, where a mosfet and control circuitry are in one package. They can be separate, where an ideal diode controller IC drives the gate of an external mosfet.
For your application, you'd need:

a source of auxiliary supply to drive mosfet gates - this can be derived (buck/boost-ed) from rectified AC inputs; since the power needed is quite low, this won't be dissipating much heat;
mosfets that will act like ideal diodes,
comparators that control the mosfets to make them act like ideal diodes,
gate drivers.

Instead of #3 and #4 you could use an ideal diode controller, but those suffer from availability issues and can cost more than more generic parts.

Re, "signal processor" vs. "ideal rectifier." You could go on to say that the "output" current from the signal processor circuit comes through the op-amp's power supply pins. It does not come through the "input" pin.
